# How to not repeat == many times

Tags: javascript

This is my example

```
if(someString == 'string1' || someString == 'string2' || someString == 'string3' || someString == 'string4');
```

Is there any trick to using shorter syntax?

Comment: Have you considered that, just because the syntax is shorter it may take longer upon execution, if you change it. Of course, it depends what you're trying to achieve. If any of those or conditions is truthy, the next one in line is not executed.

Comment: `if(",str1,str2,str3,str4,".split(","+term+",")[1])` for golfing... maybe `["str1","str2","str3","str4"].some(/./.test, RegExp("str2"))` for fun

Comment: `if(/^string[\d]$/.test(str))` is a handy way, if you have patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(["str1","str2","str3","str4"].includes(someString)){
}
```

Comment: `if({str1:1,str2:1,str3:1,str4:1}[someString])` will run much faster, as there's no method call. it's also backwards compatible with every version of JS. caching the look up array/object outside a function will enhance performance even more by avoiding object creation. `:1` is the same overhead as `""` too...

Answer (score 1):

Yes :))

```
['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'].indexOf(s) != -1
```

Comment: This is very short, but it won't have optimal performance (it's O(n), it can be less)

Comment: ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'].indexOf(s) >= 0 .  << reduced by 1 char :D

Comment: you can also do: if (~['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'].indexOf(s)) {...}  that would be reduced 2 characters more :P

Answer (score 1):

You could always put the possible values into an array, and then check whether the string matches any of the values in the array:

```js
var someString = 'string2';
var possibleValues = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"];

if (possibleValues.indexOf(someString) > -1) {
  console.log('Matched at index: ' + possibleValues.indexOf(someString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a pre-defined [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of the values you want to check, and use the `.has()` method to test for it:

```js
var vals = new Set(['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4']);
var someString = "string2";
var otherString = "stringX";

console.log(vals.has(someString));  // true
console.log(vals.has(otherString)); // false
```

So with an `if` statement, it would look like this:

```
if (vals.has(someString)) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: i like how this gives you a native method to pass around, but it must be slower to run than about any other option right?

Comment: @dandavis: I would imagine that this would be among the fastest options. AFAIK, it should be an O(1) lookup from a hash table. But then I haven't tested it and don't know how optimized these are just yet. Naturally, the `Set` should only be created once, and not every time the check needs to happen.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like if(string == "str1" || "str2" || ...,
at least not in the languages i know, and it actually makes sense there isn't, because everything is a logical expression. if you have a large number of comparisons, you can do something like

```
strings = ["str1", "str2", "str3", ...];
var match = false;
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
if(strings[i] == someString){ match = true; break; }
}
if(match){ ... do something }
```

if you only have primitive objects and non-complex comparisons (just finding something), you can use string / array methods as well

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (someString) {
case "string1":
case "string2":
case "string3":
case "string4":
   // do something
   break;
default:
   // this would the else
}
```

- Note the missing breaks on purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use include and add all the possibilities into an array:

```js
var matches = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4'];
var something = 'string2';
var isInArray = matches.includes(something);
console.log(isInArray); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 *includes* will do it

```
const options = ['string1','string2','string3'];

if (options.includes(someString)) {
  // do something
}
```